# How to switch entire XCode project to previous commit

Tags: ios, xcode, git

I am using Git and SourceTree with my project. I want to switch the whole project to a previous commit to trace where I have introduced a bug. When I do so (using SourceTree) XCode no longer thinks my project is a valid iOS project.

The scheme changes from:

[image]

to:

[image]

and I can no longer build.

What is going on here? Is XCode keeping some additional state that is preventing me from being able to switch the whole project to a previous version?

Comment: Is git giving you any errors?

Comment: *"I can no longer build"*: Why not? What errors do you see?

Comment: Generally you should be able to switch between commits with no problem. In the old version, perhaps you do not have a deployment target or base SDK selected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no bug you just need to recreate the schemes. Click on your target "MyRecipeIndex" -> "Manage Schemes" - delete everything -> "Autocreate schemes now". You should be able to build the project after that.

Comment: Yes, you are right. The autocreate schemes worked. But why do the schemes not persist when I switch between commits?